# not getting the parent view elements in adapter

Tags: java, android

I have an adapter called `PaymentMethodAdapter`. I am trying to access it's parent view element, which is already there in `xml`.

```
ViewGroup parentView;
LinearLayout listView;

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    parentView = parent;
    listView = (LinearLayout) parentView.findViewById(R.id.ben_pay_methods);
}
```

I am getting `nullpointer exception` error:

**TRACE**

```
01-20 13:22:47.075    6569-6569/com.example.android.mtesapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.mtesapp, PID: 6569
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.android.mtesapp.PaymentMethodAdapter.getView(PaymentMethodAdapter.java:65)
        at com.example.android.mtesapp.EditBeneficiaryActivity.show_receiving_methods(EditBeneficiaryActivity.java:315)
        at com.example.android.mtesapp.EditBeneficiaryActivity$AsyncTaskGetBenPaymentMethods.onPostExecute(EditBeneficiaryActivity.java:299)
        at com.example.android.mtesapp.EditBeneficiaryActivity$AsyncTaskGetBenPaymentMethods.onPostExecute(EditBeneficiaryActivity.java:283)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I check the elements in the parent view exist or not?

**EDIT**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/panelLayout"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/panel1"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                style="@style/panelFrame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:id="@+id/ben_pic"
                    android:src="@drawable/bee"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="John Doe"
                    android:id="@+id/ben_first_name"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ben_pic"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ben_pic"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ben_pic"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:hint="First Name"

                    android:background="@drawable/blue_edit_text_holo_light"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="John Doe"
                    android:id="@+id/ben_last_name"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/ben_first_name"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ben_pic"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ben_pic"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:hint="Last Name"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_edit_text_holo_light"
                   />
               <!-- <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="someone@something.com"
                    android:id="@+id/ben_email"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/ben_last_name"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ben_pic"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ben_pic"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_edit_text_holo_light"/>-->
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="647-777-0000"
                    android:hint="@string/phone"
                    android:id="@+id/ben_phone1"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/ben_last_name"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ben_pic"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ben_pic"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_edit_text_holo_light"/>

                <Button
                    style="@style/BtnDanger"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Delete"
                    android:id="@+id/delete_ben_btn"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/ben_phone1"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ben_pic"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ben_pic"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
/>
            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/panelLayout"
            android:id="@+id/panel2">
            <TextView
                style="@style/title_inside"
                android:text="@string/address" />


                <EditText
                    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ben_address1"
                    android:text="123 Something Ave"
                    android:hint="@string/address"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_edit_text_holo_light">

                </EditText>

                <!--<TextView
                    style="@style/LabelEdit"
                    android:text="@string/address" />-->



                <EditText
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ben_address2"
                    android:text=""
                    android:hint="@string/address2"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_edit_text_holo_light">


                </EditText>

                <EditText
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ben_city"
                    android:text="Toronto"
                    android:hint="@string/city"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_edit_text_holo_light">

                </EditText>

                <EditText
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ben_province"
                    android:text="Ontario"
                    android:hint="@string/province"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_edit_text_holo_light">

                </EditText>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
                    android:id="@+id/ben_country"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/country"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_edit_text_holo_light"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/panelLayout"
            android:id="@+id/panel3">
            <TextView
                style="@style/title_inside"
                android:text="@string/receive_method" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/ben_pay_methods"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
                >
                </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                style="@style/BtnInfo"
                android:id="@+id/btn_add_new_method"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="add_new_method"
                android:text="@string/add_new_method"/>



        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button
        style="@style/BtnPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/btn_edit_beneficiary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/save"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you provide the hole XML file which contains the ParentView

Comment: what makes you think that `parentView` is not null ? (hint: according to the stacktrace, it is.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @RonakPatel I don't see any thing in your XML file which works with adapters , are you working with `AdapterView` , because the ParentView is setted once you invoked the `setAdapter` on an `AdapterView`

Answer (score 0):

use convertView for inflating any view from item view of list

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_xml, null);
        listView = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ben_pay_methods);
}
```

Comment: the xml you have pasted above is your list item, right ?

Comment: What do you mean by list item?

Comment: public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) this method belong to adapter. So in adapter we always inflate our list view item and set their value according to it.

Comment: It says that I can not call `getActivity()` here.. can not resolve method

Answer (score 0):

As @Fouad Wahabi has already suggested in the comment, I found your layout XML is invalid.

There is no View with id of **layout1**. And also, though the LinearLayout is not a child View of RelativeLayout, it has an **android:layout_below** attibute. This can cause the error.

Try to remove the attribute like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/ben_pay_methods"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I just removed that line. Still, facing the same issue.

Comment: Hmm I have no more idea. @Kavis could help you.